# Noise distribution used by F-Curve Modifier

Tags: modifiers, fcurves

What is the distribution used by Blender to generate the random noise patterns in the F-Curve Modifier?

Comment: hm, sorry, it's not a perlin. [This is it](http://www.letworyinteractive.com/blendercode/dd/d05/noise_8c_source.html#l00262) but i don't know that is it.